# How to modify the line width of ipython notebook markdown cell

Tags: css, ipython, markdown, jupyter-notebook

I use ipython notebook to keep my diary using the markdown cell. The problem is that The linewidth of the cell is a little too wide, not very fine looking as a blog. The question is: **how can I decrease the width of the line and keep it stay in the middle(or left) of the page?**

The method should be easy and not affect other cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the CSS applied to the text cells via your custom.css

Simply add the following lines

```css
div.text_cell {
    width:550px;
}
```

with this the notebook looks like
[image]

There are a bunch of questions here, dealing with styling the notebook via the custom css, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19850829/2870069), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23370670/2870069), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18024769/2870069).